# See if properties file has just been created

Tags: java, properties

In my game that I am making, there is a Properties file that stores the difficulty, high score etc.

What I would like to do is see if the properties file has just been created or if the section is null (if the option isn't there)

Comment: I don't know how to do it, so thats why I came here. There is no method that is something like properties.exists()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the `java.io.File:`

```
import java.io.*;
File f=new File("filePathName");
    if(f.exists()&&!f.isDirectory()){
        //Insert specific code
}
```

Comment: Do you also know how to get the properties file location?

Comment: Try using absolute path. This would be:    `String filepath=f.getAbsolutePath();` That should assign the rile path including the filename to the variable filepath.

Comment: Nono, like getting the directory of the properties file so I can use that as the file path name.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand but for example you attempt to create some file name `Filename` but you want to also find the full path location ie `C://SomeFolder//Fiename.txt` and then see if that file exists or not by using it's potential file path? If that is the case using `f.getAbsolutePath();` will return the path ie`C://SomeFolder//Fiename.txt`. But if that isn't what you want can you please clarify, thanks!